# Arduino Serial Communication outside an interrupt

Tags: c, arduino, real-time, interrupt, sensors

I am working with arduino to calculate speed of wheel. I use Hall Effect Sensor. Every one second i update my speed value with the new RPM calculated with it. How to send data outside the one second condition in the code without affecting my calculation

```
 // read RPM

 volatile int rpmcount = 0;//see http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Volatile
 int rpm = 0;
 unsigned long lastmillis = 0;

 void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  attachInterrupt(0, rpm_fan, FALLING);//interrupt cero (0) is on pin two(2).
 }

 void loop(){

  if (millis() - lastmillis == 1000){  /*Uptade every one second, this will be equal to reading           frecuency (Hz).*/

  detachInterrupt(0);    //Disable interrupt when calculating


  rpm = rpmcount * 60;  /* Convert frecuency to RPM, note: this works for one interruption per      full rotation. For two interrups per full rotation use rpmcount * 30.*/

  Serial.print("RPM =\t"); //print the word "RPM" and tab.
  Serial.print(rpm); // print the rpm value.
  Serial.print("\t Hz=\t"); //print the word "Hz".
  Serial.println(rpmcount); /*print revolutions per second or Hz. And print new line or enter.*/

  rpmcount = 0; // Restart the RPM counter
  lastmillis = millis(); // Uptade lasmillis
  attachInterrupt(0, rpm_fan, FALLING); //enable interrupt
   }
 }


 void rpm_fan(){ /* this code will be executed every time the interrupt 0 (pin2) gets low.*/
   rpmcount++;
 }
```

i need to update some other value every 50 millisecond, how to do that ??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TimeOne.h](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne) to add an ISR to occur at 50ms, in a similar fashion to attachInterrupt(). There are also libraries for Timer2. The Timer functions often used to generate a PWM or hardware pin function. Where these libraries configure their Interrupt for overflow and disconnect them from their associated pins.

Note Timer0 is used by the Arduino Core library to generate a 1ms Interrupt as to update the millis() counter. Timer1 and 2 are typically free for general use, unless used in other 2nd party libraries.

Comment: Good, i will try that solution. Thank you